# How do I move the geth file to my external drive?

Tags: terminal, ethereum, geth, solid-state-drive

I was in the process of downloading the ethereum blockchain into my computer so i can make it function as a node on the system. I used brew to install geth. After a few hours passed the file ended up taking all the space on my computer with it only partially downloaded. I have an external SSD/ Samsung X5 connected to the computer. How do i move the whole file from my computers ssd to the external ssd. I can't seem to find where the file is saved.

Comment: This is not a programming related question, but a question for https://ethereum.stackexchange.com

Comment: alright thank you @MikkoOhtamaa